# Amazon product api import to DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, affiliate

I've got access to the Amazon products API and I would like to create a website around it.

To create a website I thought on access the API and import the products information into database than use the information to create page and add a products description.

I have a few questions about it:

1. How I can save the relevant products into my database? I'm using PHP.
2. What is the best way to build this kind of website?

Answer (score 0):

You got taken a wonderful initiative.

Below AWS technologies will help you to achieve in a scalable way.

**DynamoDB:**

To store data you can use DynamoDB,

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/

To use with php,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html

**S3 with cloudfront:**

To serve static webcontent you can use s3 and cloudfront.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html

S3 PHP API:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html

You might not need API for cloudfront initially, manual configuration might work. But below is for reference,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-cloudfront.html

Be prepared to read a lot. Since you could build with some innovative product that could help millions of people.

Good Luck!